# Which Android file should I install on VirtualBox in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, android

I would like to install Android in VirtualBox 5.2 in Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm using [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/) and it points me to [the Android x86.org download page](http://www.android-x86.org/download), but I'm not sure which file I need from this page.

Which Android file shall I download?

Thanks.

Comment: The ISO of the Android version you want to install?

Comment: Seems like neither Vbox nor Ubuntu is the issue here, so how is this question related to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you boot a new guest OS for the first time in VirtualBox you must choose a virtual optical disk file and that file must be an ISO image, the same as for making an Ubuntu live DVD/USB. Click on the guest OS -> click the gear-shaped *Settings* icon ⚙️ -> *Storage* -> after where it says *Optical Drive* select an .iso file.

[image]